# ruby (extrat the ip address last login and sort them)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

First I have a file derived from the last command in Linux. But I have hard  time to figure out how to extract and sort every IP address   and  last  command  for each user. This  actually how  the  file  looks like:

```
frank    pts/5        192.220.128.18   Thu Dec 13 21:47   still logged in 
enha     pts/3        17.0.0.206       Thu Dec 12 21:09   still logged in
skr      pts/1        184.31.240.205   Thu Dec 19 18:57 - 21:18  (02:20)
skr      pts/6        182.31.40.205    Thu Oct 24 16:42 - 16:53  (00:10)
skr      pts/7        182.31.40.205    Thu Oct 24 15:35 - 15:42  (00:06)
frank    pts/6        177.31.20.205    Thu Avr 24 15:33 - 15:42  (00:08)
sama     pts/5        190.150.128.25   Thu Avr 25 15:03 - 17:03  (02:00)
ccorn    pts/3        100.10.128.27    Thu Sep 24 14:17 - 14:26  (00:08)
```

And this is the output I'm looking for:

```
UserName,Last Login,Total Logins,IP Address List
frank,Nov 13 21:47,2,192.220.128.18;177.31.20.205
skr,Dec 19 18:57,3,182.31.40.205;188.31.40.205
sama,Avr 25 15:03,1,190.150.128.2
```

i was able to count for example how may each user login but i could not figure the rest and sort them as expect to be
this is what I done so far

```
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
login = []

lines =File.readlines("file.txt")
lines.each do |line|
login << line.split[0]

end
#p login

login.each do |user|
  frequencies[user] += 1
end
  p frequencies
```

and  thanks  in advance

Comment: Time to start coding. What have you tried?

Comment: It looks like csv formated file. You can use gem to parse it.

Comment: no is not csv formated file

Answer (score 0):

OK - one-liner's are not your friend - so let's be verrry elaborate

read raw text into array of lines

```
lines = File.readlines("file.txt")
```

parse each line into array of variables

```
parse_result = lines.map do |line|
    line.match(/(.........)(.............)(.................)(.*)/)[1..4].map(&:strip)  
end
```

aggregate and some calculations

```
aggregate_hash = parse_result.inject({}) do |memo, arr|
    name, not_needed, ip, time_info = arr   # value array into named variables for readability  

    memo[name] ||= {}  # initialize calculations hash  

    memo[name][:count] ||= 0  
    memo[name][:count] += 1   # count no of logins  

    memo[name][:ip] ||= []  
    memo[name][:ip]<<ip;      # aggregate ips into a list  

    memo[name][:last_login] ||= Time.at(0)  
    memo[name][:last_login] = [  
        memo[name][:last_login],      
        Time.parse(time_info.gsub(/(^................).*/, '\1'))      
    ].max  # get latest time (beware year is missing in input - some assumption has to be made)    

    memo  
end  

=> {"frank"=>{:count=>2, :ip=>["192.220.128.18", "177.31.20.205"], :last_login=>2016-12-13 21:47:00 +0100},
 "enha"=>{:count=>1, :ip=>["17.0.0.206"], :last_login=>2016-12-12 21:09:00 +0100},
 "skr"=>{:count=>3, :ip=>["184.31.240.205", "182.31.40.205", "182.31.40.205"], :last_login=>2016-12-19 18:57:00 +0100},
 "sama"=>{:count=>1, :ip=>["190.150.128.25"], :last_login=>2016-11-25 15:03:00 +0100},
 "ccorn"=>{:count=>1, :ip=>["100.10.128.27"], :last_login=>2016-09-24 14:17:00 +0200}}
```

;-) Happy coding

Comment: Gernot i tried but it give  an  error. I love to see what  you  did line by line, this why i can understand each  step what  it  does.  for  example  a  hash for  the  the login  frequency  also  and  main  hash  like  you  done { {"login"=>{:count, :ip, :lastlogin}

Comment: I edited my original answer to be very elaborate - just for you.  This is just basic programming practice and should normally not be placed here.  You should consult a good text book before you continue.

Comment: Thanks Gernot. I appreciate your  help